# How to write the filename on top-left corner of each page of documentclass article

Tags: header-footer, article, jobname

How to add the document's filename at the top left corner of each page in the following minimum working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
    % \markboth{\jobname}{\jobname}
    Hello!
    \clearpage
    This is the second page.
\end{document}
```

I have tried `\markboth{\jobname}{\jobname}` just after `\begin{document}` but in vain.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your code is fine. You just need to switch from the default page style of the `article` document class (`plain`) to a page style that allows for a non-empty header line. LaTeX provides the `myheadings` page styles for your purpose. (The page style `headings` might work as well -- but only if the document doesn't contain any section-level headers.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{myheadings}
\begin{document}
    \markboth{\jobname}{\jobname}
    Hello!
    \clearpage
    This is the second page.
\end{document}
```

Comment: If I have a section heading, then the `\pagestyle{headings}` gave me the section heading instead of the filename. In such case, the `\pagestyle{myheadings}` gave me the filename on each page.

Comment: @MMKhan - Many thanks for this feedback. I will update my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 5):

For example with the `fancyhdr` package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}
    \markboth{}{\jobname}
    Hello!
    \clearpage
    This is the second page.
\end{document}
```

Comment: fancyhdr is adding this horizontal line which I do not want. The \pagestyle{headings} is fine without using the fancyhdr package. Thanks.