# How to write the filename on top left corner of the title page?

Tags: header-footer, titles, article, jobname

I tried the below-mentioned minimum working example. The difference from my earlier question on StackExchange (click [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/430008/how-to-write-the-filename-on-top-left-corner-of-each-page-of-documentclass-artic)) is that we have now a title page. 
How to write the document's filename on the top-left corner of the title page as well?

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{myheadings}

\begin{document}
    \markboth{\jobname}{\jobname}   
    \begin{titlepage}
        \pagestyle{headings}
        \centering
        {\bf\Large Probability distribution modeling} \\
        Muhammad Khan
    \end{titlepage}

    \section{Introduction}
    Hello!
\end{document}
```

Comment: use `\thispagestyle{headings}` instead of `\pagestyle{headings}` within the `titlepage`. (But this will put a page number too, which may not be what you want.)

Comment: How to NOT add the page number then?

Comment: The simplest solution would be `\def\thepage{}` before the `\thispagestyle` command inside the `titlepage`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `\thispagestyle{headings}` on top or instead of `\pagestyle{headings}`. You can keep `\pagestyle{headings}`

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{myheadings}

\begin{document}
    \markboth{\jobname}{\jobname}   
    \begin{titlepage}
        \thispagestyle{headings}
        \centering
        {\bf\Large Probability distribution modeling} \\
        Muhammad Khan
    \end{titlepage}
    \markboth{\jobname}{\jobname}   
    \pagestyle{headings}
    \section{Introduction}
    Hello!
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is a very good answer. But how can I make the filename bold and normal ?!. This code writes the filename with a little inclination to the right.